# CustomTab add-ins Manifest xml not working Excel 2016

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

We have created xml with custom tabs. Its working in office 365 online but not on Desktop.

Comment: You need to provide more detailed information, such as the relevant part of the manifest XML and the build of Excel 2016 where it's "not working". Also, please specify what is meant by "not working": Is the Ribbon customization not appearing? Is the code not executing? Something else?

Comment: @SameerShaikh, Could you please provide more information?

Comment: We use manifest with add-in command. Please refer code.

Comment: We use manifest with add-in command.<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
  <CustomTab id="Contoso Tab">
    <Label resid="residLabel4" />
    <Group id="Group1Id12">
      <Label resid="residLabel4" />
      <Icon>
        <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_32x32" />
        <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon1_32x32" />
        <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_32x32" />
      </Icon>
      <Tooltip resid="residToolTip" />
      <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button1Id1"> 
      </Control>
    </Group>
  </CustomTab>
</ExtensionPoint>

Comment: After inserting manifest xml from add-ins in Desktop Excel 2016 Custom tab is not displaying.

Comment: @SameerShaikh, Thanks for providing information. We are looking into it.

Comment: @TrinetraMSFT, any update?